# List all objects ( instances ) created in the JVM Heap

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

The objects in java are stored in the heap. Within my Java program I need code that does this task:

At a given moment, how can I list all the objects existing in the heap?

```
List<Object> listOfObjectsInHeap = ...  ?
```

Comment: You need to use a tool like `jhat`; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jhat.html

Comment: A Java profiler will show this info in a comfortable manner: https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What are you [exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70504779/2541560) doing?

Comment: You can try heap dump your self. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html

Comment: Both `jhat` and `jprofiler` are Java programs.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM provides an interface, called JVMTI, that can be used for this purpose. Originally meant to connect profiling tools, it also can be abused for your purpose, also from inside your program.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html